# How to get mod rewrite to change an url's symbol for display purposes?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Good day all,

Ive been wondering, google searching and goign greyer quicker thinking if it is possible for mod rewrite to change a specific symbol it grabs from the url to something else?

i.e. if the url is www.website.com/foo-bar using the rewriterule I can get that hyphen to become a forward slash?

```
<?php $foobar = "foo-bar"; ?>

<a href="/<?php echo $foobar; ?>">foo-bar</a>
```

.htacces code I have..

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$        index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So basically I would like mod rewrite to make the url display on the addressbar as www.website.com/foo/bar if possible?

Regards,

Dan.

Comment: exactly what u need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919378/search-and-replace-in-apache-htaccess-a-rewriterule

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?t=2799

Comment: Dont think that will work for me as I already explode the GET by the hyhens for use with an URL friendly slug from the db. I was typically hoping that mod_rewrite could actually transform a hyphen into a forward slash in itself and not through using PHP. If anyone else knows if mod-rewrite can do this I would be very greatful. Dan.