# htaccess redirect using mod_rewrite for seo friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to trim down my urls using htaccess having my index.php act as the key with the following code:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1 [NC]
```

To use this with my members area, do i just add the following to work on mysite.com/members/index.php?city=$1

```
      RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1 [NC]
```

in the event of a city having multiple words, ie: new york city, whats the best way to approach this? defining it in the .htaccess (not sure if thats possible) to change new york city -> new-york-city or actually any space to a dash.  Or, do it in php with a function to replace ' ' -> '-' for the db queries that use $_GET?

Answer (score 5):

I would replace spaces with dashes in PHP and then redirect to the new version of the URL to get easily readable addresses. (Space is encoded as %20 which is not exactly easily readable)

That way you would still be able to enter the address `domain.com/new york city` but would be redirected to `domain.com/new-york-city` instead of `domain.com/new%20york%20city`.

The replace in .htaccess is possible with something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\s]*)\s(.*) $1-$2 [N]
```

(Based on answer to [Search and replace in apache htaccess a RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919378/search-and-replace-in-apache-htaccess-a-rewriterule))

Comment: I tried using that, it returned a 500 error, going to research it more to see if i can debug that.

Comment: I take that back, it does pass properly (i pasted wrong the first time), but its coinciding with what I already have, RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1 [NC] passes city= as test.php

Comment: Did you place the space-replacer before your original RewriteRule?

Comment: No. You write test.php, where did that come from?

Comment: for testing purposes, i changed RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1 [NC]
to be test.php?city=$1