# How can I write a regex to match everything but a char?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've switched in my wordpress blog from urls like this:

```
/blog/2012/01/01/how-to-build-a-website
```

To shorter urls like this

```
/blog/?p=123
```

Wordpress has a search engine who works like this

```
/blog/search/?s=how to build a website
```

And search for the `s` params.

I'm trying to use .htaccess Redirectmatch to redirect all the old urls to the search url with the title of the post as the `s` params.

So if the user serf to

```
/blog/2012/01/01/how-to-build-a-website
```

should be redirect to

```
/blog/search/?s=how to build a website
```

I've coded this

```
Redirectmatch blog/\d+/\d+/\d+/(.+) http://www.mysite.com/blog/?s=$1
```

But this regex grap the whole string after the last `/` within the `-` symbol inside it.

In this way if a user serf to

```
/blog/2012/01/01/how-to-build-a-website
```

Will be redirected to

```
/blog/search/?s=how-to-build-a-website
```

while I want the user redireced to

```
/blog/search/?s=how to build a website
```

How can I write the regex to do this?

EDIT:
Yes guys, I know that this kind of urls are ugly :) But I just would know how to do it, because behind this there are some technical issues I'm trying to solve..

Comment: Why would you switch from beautiful URLs to ugly ones? Why?

Comment: can i recomendate the plugin [smart 404](http://atastypixel.com/blog/wordpress/plugins/smart-404/), that should solve this without using .htacess

Comment: Ditto what @AnthonyMills asked. The long URLs is one of Wordpress's strengths. You get great SEO. Choosing shorter URLs like you are is a great way to make sure that people **cannot google for your posts**.

Comment: have you read [search and replace in apache htaccess a rewriterule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919378/search-and-replace-in-apache-htaccess-a-rewriterule), and +1 to Anthony and Dogweather

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. I know it can seem tempting to go for short URLs; after all, you get things like TinyURL and such. Isn't it better to have `/blog/?p=123` than `/blog/2012/01/01/how-to-build-a-website`?

No. It's not.

The reason is because when someone posts a link to your blog article, the longer URL *means something*. It tells the person how old the article is. It gives the title. It helps people find your article; after all, the URL is given a lot of weight by Google when indexing your site.

URLs used to be built for computers. Something like `/blog/?p=123` is perfect for computers; it's easy to parse, it doesn't require any extra database lookups. You can write two articles named "How to Build a Website" and the blog engine doesn't have to make sure it adds a `-2` on the second one. It maps easily to the actual structure of files on the server, without making up structure in the URL.

But we've realized since that URLs can be built for humans, too. The URL `/blog/2012/01/01/how-to-build-a-website` has a form that can be easily understood by humans. Sure, it's a bit longer to type, but all the bits you're typing are easier, and most URLs are copy'n'pasted anyway or just clicked on. It's more work for the computer, sure, but it's worth it. **It makes the Internet friendlier.**

So I'm sorry, but I won't help you. :)

Comment: Yes guys, I know that this kind of urls are ugly :) But I just would know how to do it, because behind this there are some technical issues I'm trying to solve..

Comment: Anyways, I agree everything you said