# htaccess rewrite part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

i have i links - for example:

```
/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=1&sid=1&tid=10&minprice=15000
```

and i need to change '`tid=10`' - for something else let's say '`cid=105`'
this will help me to make a component to work like i want without touching it

for example the links

```
/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=1&sid=1&tid=10&minprice=15000
```

or

```
/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=3&tid=10
```

or

```
/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=1&sid=6&tid=10&minprice=234235235
```

and so on - will became the same, but with  '`tid=10`' part been change to '`cid=105`'

`/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=1&tid=10&123`   ==>   `/nedvizhimost.html?cyid=1&cid=105&123`

I have no clue how to do it, already spend more then 3 hours for that - read a lot of anwers in this site, but unfortunately i can't find the solution. Please help me!

i saw [Search and replace in apache htaccess a RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919378/search-and-replace-in-apache-htaccess-a-rewriterule) this theme about search and replace - but i dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)tid=10(&[a-z].*)?$
RewriteRule ^nedvizhimost.html$ /nedvizhimost.html?%1cid=105%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: is there other way to do it? i dont care how - i just need to change that url..

Comment: @user2985719 Any other way is not going to involve using htaccess, but those rules [work perfectly fine for me in a blank htaccess file](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BiI81.png).

Comment: i will try to use those lines in a blank htaccess too - 1 moment ... YEEESSSS IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!

Comment: @user2985719 they need to be *before* any rules that do routing (ones without the `R` flag)