# replace a character with "/" in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, replace, subdirectory

I'm using an specific script which only recognize a single folder for custom made pages, that forced me to save all my tpl files there, files names was like mydomain.com/a=cust&page=books.example

I have removed query string from the url using rewritecond and rewriterule and added .html to the URL. Now they appear like mydomain.com/books.example.html

is there any option in htaccess to replace a character of file name with "/" ? 
i need htaccess to automatically find the defined character in file name and replace it with / in the URL in order to build virtual folders.(i am using an specific script which is impossible to make sub-folders in it).
for example file name is : 
cat.books.name.tpl or cat.books.name.html
i want .htaccess to replace "." with "/" (or any other characters if it do) :
mydomain.com/cat/books/name/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search and replace in apache htaccess a RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919378/search-and-replace-in-apache-htaccess-a-rewriterule)